# Django Template How to Show Money Values like 4.8p

Tags: python, django

I have a template which displays a cost per message currently this displays in html as:

**(0.048p per message)**

**But, I want the output to be (4.8p per text).**

I have tried |floatformat etc, but it either rounds up i.e. 5p or does not work.

In my Template:

```
 <span class="term">({{ "Micro"|unit_cost:100 }}p per message)</span>
```

Template Tag Function:

```
def unit_cost(value, arg):
    credit_object = CreditCalculator(arg)
    unit_cost = credit_object.get_unit_cost()
    return unit_cost
```

UPDATE: I want to do this in the template not change the function as its used elsewhere. i.e. I want to do something like: `({{ "Micro"|unit_cost:100|floatformat }}`

Comment: Can you pass another param? Instead of 100, 10 or 1000. Just for this special case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template tag is just a way to use Python within a template. One possible soultion is to wrap unit_cost in another function so that it's untouched. This is just one way i.e.

In your tags:

```
def multiply_cost(value):
    return value*100

register.filter('multiply_cost', multiply_cost)
```

Then:

```
({{ "Micro"|unit_cost:100|multiply_cost }}p per message)
```

This will give: value as x.x as required. You can expand on this, for example pass in a multiply by arg etc, but for get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the value by 100:

```
def unit_cost(value, arg):
     # ...
     return unit_cost*100
```

Comment: I don't want to change the function, just how its rendered i.e. ({{ "Micro"|unit_cost:100|floatformat }} etc.